# How to check which links were clicked by a user on two variations in Google Analytics A/B testing experiment?

Tags: javascript, html, web, google-analytics

I have run a Google Analytics behavior experiment to choose a winner from two design variations of a website. I have found a winner but I wanna know in both variations which areas did the user interact when they visited one of the both web page variations. How can I do this? There are event tracking set in my website but that is an overall result that shows in that particular tab in Google Analytics. How can I filter out the specific events that the user has triggered on two versions of the same website or page? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Variant](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=content_experiments&jump=ga_experimentvariant) dimension to view the total events in each variation.

Comment: How can I implement this?

Comment: @techytee do you know how to create custom reports in Google Analytics? Or how to use Core Reporting API?
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference